# How to rotate an image in Glide to be right side up

Tags: android, image, image-resizing, android-glide, image-rotation

I am a little bit of a novice Android developer but I am working on a project to improve memory efficiency in our app's handling of images.

Right now, we have some code for rotating an image based on the Exif data to ensure that it's right side up. I'd like to do the same thing but in Glide, but I can't find any documentation on that... or even documentation on reading Exif data.

I have to imagine this is a fairly common use case! I'd like to take the following code and reduce it to a straightforward Glide method.

Here's what we have now:

```
final Matrix bitmapMatrix = new Matrix();
int widthMultiplier = 1;
int heightMultiplier = 1;
try {
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new ByteArrayInputStream(bo.toByteArray()));
    final Collection<ExifIFD0Directory> exifIFD0Directories = metadata.getDirectoriesOfType(ExifIFD0Directory.class);
    if (exifIFD0Directories != null) {
        for (ExifIFD0Directory d : exifIFD0Directories) {
            if (d.containsTag(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION)) {
                try {
                    final int exifOrientation = d.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);

                    switch (exifOrientation) {
                        case 1:
                            break;  // top left
                        case 2:
                            heightMultiplier = -1;
                            break;  // top right
                        case 3:
                            bitmapMatrix.postRotate(180);
                            break;  // bottom right
                        case 4:
                            bitmapMatrix.postRotate(180);
                            heightMultiplier = -1;
                            break;  // bottom left
                        case 5:
                            bitmapMatrix.postRotate(90);
                            heightMultiplier = -1;
                            break;  // left top
                        case 6:
                            bitmapMatrix.postRotate(90);
                            break;  // right top
                        case 7:
                            bitmapMatrix.postRotate(270);
                            heightMultiplier = -1;
                            break;  // right bottom
                        case 8:
                            bitmapMatrix.postRotate(270);
                            break;  // left bottom
                        default:
                            break;  // Unknown
                    }
                    break;
                } catch (MetadataException e) {
                    handleException(e, subscriber, uri, inputStream, mFinalPath, fromGallery);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

} catch (ImageProcessingException | IOException e) {
    handleException(e, subscriber, uri, inputStream, mFinalPath, fromGallery);
    return;
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some additional resource, it sounds as if Glide actually handles this automatically.